# Wiping ALL Kafka data?

Tags: apache-kafka

Running Kafka on Windows 10 x64. I stopped Zookeeper and Kafka. Deleted the logs folder in both. Deleted my kafka-streams folder. But still, when I start Kafka up, I get a bunch of:

[2020-04-02 10:32:46,717] INFO [Partition xxx-stream-e1d97106-95ab-4f64-a692-ebfe73382e4c-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition-0 broker=0] No checkpointed highwatermark is found for partition xxx-stream-e1d97106-95ab-4f64-a

and about consumer offsets.

Where is it storing this stuff? I thought it was all in the logs directory?

Comment: @mazaneicha I said I deleted the logs folder in both ZK and Kafka. It's still pulling the partition info from somewhere else for old partitions and streams.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding if by ZK log you really meant ZK data directory.

Comment: @mazaneicha Ooops... lol... yeah, I wiped the ZK logs and K logs :(. Brain glitch :). Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked out :)